# Exception in thread "main" javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException: no such object

Tags: java, database, jdbc, jdo, datanucleus

I'm working with JDO DataNucleus implementation and I'm having a major problem that is I can't get an object I've previously stored in the database. I'll give you all the code related.

This is the method where I create a new User (that is passed via argument) and store it in the database. This works, I can create a User and store it:

```
public void newUser(User user) throws UserException {
    PersistenceManager pm = Repository.getFactory().getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();

        // 1. Check required information has been set.
        if (user.getEmail() == null) throw new UserException("The email has not been set!!");
        if (user.getPassword() == null) throw new UserException("The password has not been set!!");

        // 2. Check the user has not been created before.
        Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT count(email) FROM " + User.class.getName() + " WHERE email=='" + user.getEmail() + "'");
        Long count = (Long)q.execute();
        if (count > 0) throw new UserException("The user already exists!!");

        // 3. Everything correct: create the user
        pm.makePersistent(user);
        tx.commit();

    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive())
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

The class Repository is a wrapper, so I don't need to establish the jdo.properties link everytime. Here you have the method where I retrieve a User. This doesn't work, I can't retrieve a User I've created previously, the message *Exception in thread "main" javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException: no such object* appears:

```
public void updateUser(User user) throws UserException {
    PersistenceManager pm = Repository.getFactory().getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();

        // 1. Check required information has been set.
        if (user.getEmail() == null) throw new UserException("The email has not been set!!");

        // 2. Check the user HAS BEEN created before.
        Query countQuery = pm.newQuery("SELECT count(email) FROM " + User.class.getName() + " WHERE email=='" + user.getEmail() + "'");
        Long count = (Long)countQuery.execute();
        if (count == 0) throw new UserException("The user does not exist!!");

        // 3. Update the user
        User userToUpdate = (User) pm.getObjectById(user.getEmail());

        if (!(user.getPassword() == null))
            userToUpdate.setPassword(user.getPassword());

        if (!(user.getName() == null))
            userToUpdate.setName(user.getName());

        if (!(user.getSurname() == null))
            userToUpdate.setSurname(user.getSurname());

        if (!(user.getAlias() == null))
            userToUpdate.setAlias(user.getAlias());

        if (!(user.getPicture() == null))
            userToUpdate.setPicture(user.getPicture());

        tx.commit();

    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive())
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my test class, where I test the methods:
    public class UpdateUserTest {

```
static UsersImpl users = new UsersImpl();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    User user2 = new User();
    User user3 = new User();

            user2.setEmail("user4");
    user2.setPassword("pass4");

    user3.setEmail("user4");
    user3.setPassword("pass3");
    try {
        users.newUser(user2);
        users.updateUser(user3);
    } catch (UserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this exception?
Thanks in advance.

Stacktrace:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (DataNucleus.General).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException: Objeto no existe
FailedObject:user6
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:475)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1727)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1703)
at es.diegofenollar.iap.eqp.business.UsersImpl.updateUser(UsersImpl.java:64)
at es.upv.epsa.iap.eqp.test.UpdateUserTest.main(UpdateUserTest.java:20)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
Objeto no existe
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusObjectNotFoundException: Objeto no existe
at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.getClassDetailsForId(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3499)
at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.findObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3621)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1722)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1703)
at es.diegofenollar.iap.eqp.business.UsersImpl.updateUser(UsersImpl.java:64)
at es.upv.epsa.iap.eqp.test.UpdateUserTest.main(UpdateUserTest.java:20)
```

UsersImpl.java:64 is:

```
User userToUpdate = (User) pm.getObjectById(user.getEmail());
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace and point us to that line.

Comment: Are you sure you are showing correct stacktrace? Your stacktrace has `FailedObject:user6`, but I dont see anything in your test any object passed as parameter `user6` to update? \

Comment: Ah is because I cannot delete Users yet ( I don't have any methods), so I changed the string to store "user6", since I can't create another User with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of

```
pm.getObjectById(User.class, idValue);
```

makes much more sense. Suggest you read up on JDO identity and look at the output of `pm.getObjectId(obj)`